# Keeping reference to a nested List<T> in C#

Tags: c#, data-structures, reference, tree

My task is to find paths in a tree, where the sum of the nodes make a particular sum, given at the beginning.

Example:

[image: Task]

In my implementation I keep the results in a nested List as following:

```
private void DfsPathGivenSum(Tree<T> node, List<T> list, int sum, List<List<T>> results)
{
    list.Add(node.Key);

    foreach (var child in node.children)
    {
        this.DfsPathGivenSum(child, list, sum, results);
    }

    var currentPathSum = list.Sum(x => int.Parse(x.ToString()));
    if (currentPathSum == sum)
    {
        results.Add(list);
    }

    list.RemoveAt(list.Count - 1);
}
```

When I invoke this method from another method:

```
public List<List<T>> PathsWithGivenSum(int sum)
{
    var list = new List<T>();
    var results = new List<List<T>>();
    this.DfsPathGivenSum(this, list, sum, results);

    return results;
}
```

the reference to the inner List seems to be lost. How can I deal with this issue?

Comment: You are calling `list.RemoveAt(..)`  why?

Comment: The 'list' keeps track of the current path, so list.RemoveAt() removes the element, which is no longer on the current path.

Comment: The lesson here is recursion. With recursion you are able to "walk" the tree. Here is some [documentation](https://code-maze.com/csharp-basics-recursion/) and [here](https://www.dotnetperls.com/recursion)

Comment: You shouldn't remove items from the original list.

Comment: Then how could I follow the path elements? Maybe I didn't asked the question clearly, but the implementation works perfect, it is the nested List that loses the elements when I invoke the recursive method.

Comment: @GeorgiPopov whats the reason to remove the list? As far as I understand you just want to sum up each unique path, right?

Comment: Can you end on any node or do you have to reach a leaf (ie, if you had to search for '26', will it return ['7','19'])?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

`results.Add(list)`;

to

`results.Add(list.ToList())`;

I.e. you want to create a copy of the current list when adding it to the result, otherwise you will just have a bunch of references to the same list, that will be empty at the end.

I would also suggest some better way to convert nodes to numbers than `ToString` and `int.Parse`. For example by taking a `Func<T, int>` parameter that can be supplied to the `.sum` method.

You could also improve the algorithm a bit by keeping a running sum, to avoid needing to loop over all the previous nodes for each visited node.

Comment: It's a great answer, thank you. However, I'd like to ask you how the Func improves the code since it is still transforming the generic to string and then parsing it to int: Func<T, int> selector = str => int.Parse(str.ToString());

Comment: @georgi popov Since the caller should know the actual type of `T`, it should be able to use an actual property of the object ( or the value itself in case T is int), rather than relying on the class having an overridden ToString method that returns a parsable string.

Comment: How would the compiler accept such a thing?

Comment: @georgi Popov The compiler accepts delegates since it is written to do so? Say I have a `Node` class with a `Score` property, You could give a delegate parameter like `myNode => myNode.Score` when calling the method, and the type inference would map this to a Func<Node, int> delegate type.

Answer (score 0):

As @JonasH said, you definitely need to work from a copied collection of nodes.

```
// Pseduocode:
// For each node
//   Find Path and Sum
//   If Sum correct
//     Add Path to Result


private class Node
{
    public Node Parent;
    public int score;
}

private void DfsPathGivenSum(List<Node> allNodes, int targetSum, List<List<Node>> results) {

    results.Clear();

    // Copy list of Nodes into Queue
    var pending = new Queue<Node>(allNodes); 

    // For each node in queue
    while (pending.Count > 0) {
        var currentNode = pending.Dequeue();

        // Create 'new' Path trace starting at currentNode
        var path = new List<Node> { currentNode };
        var sum = currentNode.score;

        // Iterate until at root node
        while (currentNode.Parent != null) { 
            currentNode = currentNode.Parent; // step to parent node
            path.Add(currentNode); // add to trace
            sum += currentNode.score; // add to sum
        }

        if (sum == targetSum)
            results.Add(path);
    }
}
```